# Pushing an object into an object under a certain key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve the following Array/Object,

```
[
 1:[{data:data},{data:data}]
]
```

How would this be achieved?
I got thus far,

```
var data = [];
data['1'] = {data:data}
```

but this just overwrites.

Comment: `push` ?? And you are mixing a lot of different syntaxes, your code wont work.

Comment: yeah, array's dont' have keys, either, so the closes you can get to your example is: `[{data:data},{data:data}]`

Comment: @JonasW. 
I have three different lotteries. I get data from my server, entries in lottery 1, 2 & 3. Now I would like to render these lottery entries to a chart, therefor I would need to push it all into one array, wouldn't I? (If I would want it to be easy to add more lotteries in the futures, cause I could have a seperate array for each, but that would make it difficult to add new.)

Answer (score 2):

The notation `[]` is for making [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), `{}` is for making [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

See the following

```
const data = {}; // Initialize the object
data['1'] = []// Makes data={'1':[]}
data['1'].push({data: 'data'}) // Makes data = {'1':[{data:'data'}]}
```

OR

```
const data = []; // Initialize the Array
data.push([]) // Makes data=[[]]
data[0].push({data: 'data'}) // Makes data = [[{data:'data'}]]
```

Comment: I mean I do need an array, since there are multiple objects, within the array.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right you want to push objects into an array inside of an hashtable ( which can be easily implemented using an object in javascript). 
So we need an object first:

```
 const lotteries = {};
```

Now before storing data, we need to check if the relating array exists, if not we need to create it:

```
 function addDataToLottery(lottery, data){
   if(!lotteries[lottery]){ //if it doesnt exist
     lotteries[lottery] = [];  //create a new array
   }
   //As it exists definetly now, lets add the data
   lotteries[lottery].push({data});
 }

 addDataLottery("1", { what:"ever"});

 console.log(lotteries["1"]));
```

---

PS: If you want to write it in a fancy way:

```
 class LotteryCollection extends Map {
   constructor(){
      super();
   }
   //A way to add an element to one lottery
   add(lottery, data){
     if(!this.has(lottery)) this.set(lottery, []);
     this.get(lottery).push({data});
     return this;
   }
 }

 //Create a new instance
 const lotteries = new LotteryCollection();
 //Add data to it
 lotteries
    .add("1", {what:"ever"})
    .add("1", {sth:"else"})
    .add("something", {el:"se"});

 console.log(lotteries.get("1"));
```

Comment: More than I was looking for! Great.